# Is it okay to say,what John is to Lisa?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to use the phrase  “what am I to you” but between people. If I say “what John is to Lisa is more important than collage” would it mean that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be fine.

I understand it to mean: (Maintaining) Lisa's love / dependence / respect for John is more important than (studying in) college (is to her).

P.S. "college" rather than "collage".